# React & Redux: How to prevent slice from defaulting when navigating website?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Im want to have a slice representing a user.
The slice's values are set when the user logs in.

But the problem is:

When you navigate the site, the slices and states defaults.
This means its like the user is logged out when navigating from the home page to whatever other page.
This can also be compared to having a shopping cart on a website.
I dont know how to have it so the shopping cart is not reset when you navigate the website.

How do I make it so the user can navigate the website, without being logged out/having the slices and states default?

Comment: you can use localStorage

Comment: are you having a full page refresh on page changes? What react navigation library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

## How to persist a slice ?

There are multiple way to persist a redux slice. They all depend on the final technology that is use. Is it on `iOS`, `Android`, `Web`, `HWA` etc...

You also have to chose a way to store this slice based on the confidentiality of the information.

For example on web if you want to persist a slice with the local storage you can use [`redux-persist`](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)